# biblatex: Change punctuation to semicolon before addendum field

Tags: biblatex

With `biblatex`, an `addendum` field prints at the very end of a bibliographic entry. How can the punctuation preceding it be changed to a semicolon (without changing the punctuation after all fields)?

[image: Addendum field wants semicolon not comma]

In the example illustrated above with source given below, the `addendum` field happens to be for an `article` entry, but the punctuation change needs to be robust in the sense that it could very well be for any other kind of entry, e.g., `book`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{shortbib.bib}
@article{Euler1776,
Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psych.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},Pages={1--2718},
Addendum={popularization of earlier technical article}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{shortbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm using the following `biblatex.cfg`, and I presume somehow I need to add to it.

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
%
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {title}{\emph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{{#1}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {volume}{\textbf{#1}}
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

Comment: It is a bit nicer to use `\mkbibemph` instead of `\emph` and `\mkbibbold` iunstead of `\textbf`. In `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{{#1}}` you could get rid of one pair of curly braces: `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}` is just fine. BTW: If you want all titles to be emph-ed, just go with `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can add the relevant punctuation command to the `addendum+pubstate` macro

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
```

Comment: OK! I knew it was something like that but couldn't discern the appropriate macro )`addendum+pubstate` to modify.