# Biblatex article entry: volume (year), no. n like bibtex amsplain?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

With `biblatex` I want to imitate the `amsplain` style for article entries in the bibliography. Specifically, I still need to make the volume, number, and year parts to appear in the form

> **vv** (yr), no. n

— with the "number" field following the (parenthesized) year — as in the following `amsplain` example:

[image: Article entry with amsplain bibliography style]

Here's how far I've gotten with `biblatex`. The source is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{EulerE1776,
    Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
    Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
    Year = {1776},Volume = {4},number={1},
    pages={1--2718}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And my `biblatex.cfg` is:

```
% BIBLATEX.CFG
% mimic amsplain
%
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
%
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
  %
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
%
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

The output with that `biblatex` configuration is:

[image: Biblatex article entry]

I presume I have to at least modify the definition of `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}` and perhaps modify some bibmacro, but I've been unable to penetrate the documentation to see how to do that.

*Note*: Owing to other reasons, I must use `biblatex` rather than just the `amsplain` style with `bibtex`.

Comment: You may want to check out my comments on your last question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335737/35864).

Comment: @moewe: Of course I checked those comments and used them, but the problem is that in `standard.bbx` I just don't find any mention of a `year` macro, so I don't know what to modify how.

Comment: Now I'm confused, I didn't talk about the `year` macro, did I? I said something about `\mkbibemph` instead of `\emph` etc.

Comment: Since I'm trying to move the `number` field after the `year` field, that's why I mentioned the latter.

Comment: Ah, well you'll find the answet to your question in my answer below. My comment here was just so I don't have to repeat my earlier comment. It has nothing to do with your question as such, it just gives some general hints. (I thought that since I posted the comment after my answer, you might not have read it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We only need to modify the macro `journal+issuetitle` from `standard.bbx`. Because it was easier I have scattered the definition of `volume+number+eid` throughout `journal+issuetitle` instead of retaining it as a separate macro.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}
```

We essentially split up the macro `volume+number+eid` into its volume and number parts and moved the date printing in between the two.

Comment: That works - but why? In my `.bib` file, I have a `year` field. Where/how does that get translated into the bibmacro for `journal+issuetitle`? (That's the sort of thing I'm not understanding in order to modify the style myself.)

Comment: @murray The year field gets parsed into a `date`-structure, that is printed with the macro `issue+date` we call in the code above. Unfortunately finding out where what gets printed it is not always as easy as looking for the field name. You can always start from the driver and unwrap the macro definitions by looking the up in `standard.bbx` and `biblatex.def`, that can get you quite far, but may take some time.

Comment: I don't find an `issue+date` macro defined in `standard.bbx` or in `biblatex.sty` or in 'bib latex.def` Where does it come from?

Comment: @murray It's in `standard.bbx` (line 785 on my machine). Essentially it does `\usebibmacro{date}` wrapped in `printtext[parens]` if you don't have `issuetitle` defined. `date` then is defined in `biblatex.def` as `\newbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}`. `\printdate` you can look up in the manual, or you guess from the name that it prints the date.

Comment: OK, see the explanation of `\printdate` in `biblatex.pdf` but not finding its definition in `biblatex.sty` or `standard.bbx` or `biblatex.def`. Am I just missing finding it in the actual files?

Comment: @murray `\printdate` is a bit tricky, it is defined in `biblatex.sty`in a roundabout way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47426/discussion-between-murray-and-moewe).

Comment: @murray See my comment in chat.