# Change order of volume, year and issue fields in Biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I would like to switch the order of the volume, year and issue fields of the printed bibliography items. I'm using the following code for biblatex

```
\usepackage[isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,giveninits=true,date=year]{biblatex}
```

and my output is:

[image]

what I would like to obtain is:

[image]

Where the important difference is the ordering of volume,year,issue. In the example volume is 5, year is 1997 and issue is no.3. In my code I have 5.3 (1997), while I want 5 (1997) no.3.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage[isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,giveninits=true,date=year]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @article{anderson_extrema_1997,
        title = {Extrema of curvature functionals on the space of metrics on 3-manifolds},
        volume = {5},
        issn = {0944-2669, 1432-0835},
        url = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s005260050066},
        doi = {10.1007/s005260050066},
        pages = {199--269},
        number = {3},
        journaltitle = {Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations},
        shortjournal = {Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations},
        author = {Anderson, Michael T.},
        urldate = {2024-02-07},
        date = {1997-03-01},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}
    Asd\cite[Proposition 1.1]{anderson_extrema_1997}
    
    % Bibliography
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I wanted to know if there is a quick solution or wether this requires the definition of a new style, which, by googleing a bit, looks quite complicated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the missing code, so it compiles when we copy and run your example? In this case it should at least cite and list one book, i.e. the one you mentioned. Thank you // Just in case, here's a procedure to complete what's missing into a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: @MS-SPO done, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335911/35864.

Comment: @moewe thanks, your solution works! The last thing I need is to make the volume field bold.

Comment: That would be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429519/35864 (but the question of the duplicate also already has code for the bold `volume`).